# Wcf object types

Tags: c#, wcf

Trying to send a complex type between two systems that have the same code base. They are both aware of the same object that is the data transport medium. However when I pass object on the consumer proxy it appears as an object in the web service namespace instead of the one in the application.

Is there anyway that I can define to use the internal object?

```
[WebMethod]
public void Run(TransportObject transport)
```

appears in my application under `MyNamespace.Webservice.Transport` instead of `MyNamespace.Objects`

Comment: `[WebMethod]` is not WCF - it's ASMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henk says sharing of types in WCF is default behavior.

I will qualify that by expanding on it and demonstrating how to achieve it:

So rather than have visual studio generate a service reference for you, you can have WCF create the proxy when it executes by using ChannelFactory.

For example:

```
// Create service proxy on the fly
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>("NameOfMyClientEndpointInConfigFile");
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

// Create data contract
var requestDataContract = new MyRequestType();

// Call service operation.
MyResponseType responseDataContract = proxy.MyServiceOperation(requestDataContract);
```

In the above example, `IMyServiceContract` is your service contract, and `MyRequestType` and  `MyResponseType` are your data contracts, which you can use by referencing the assembly which the service also references (which defines these types).

Answer (score 1):

`[WebMethod]` implies it's an ASMX based service, not a WCF service...

Try again with an `[OperationContract]` in a `[ServiceContract]`

Sharing of Types in WCF is possible, I think it's even the default behaviour.